Creating table from polygon or closed polylines in QGIS
Is there a way to create a table (like the green lines) on a polygon or within a closed polyline? I have imported the rectangles from AutoCAD, which have predetermined sizes so I will need to create the sizes based on that. I would like to then export the tables back into AutoCAD.
All of the segments for the table should be equal-sized too.


A correct answer would be "yes". Please provide some details by editing your question: 1. Is this a symbology or a geometry question? 2. How do you determine the size of the rectangles? 3. How do you determine their orientation? 4. What other rules are there when it comes to creating the rectangles? 5. What have you tried so far?

You could use the "Create Grid" Tool. In my simple example, I only have one polygon in my layer so I could simply calculate the extent of the grid from the layer:

This results in this grid:

Doing this for all of your polygons would require multiple manual steps of calculating the extent and running the "Create Grid" Tool. If you are familiar with PyQGIS or Model Designer, you could automate that process.

I did originally try this, but like you said you can only do it one at a time and I'd find myself spending more time doing it this way than in AutoCAD.
